# JavaMail: TLS on port 25 with separate truststore possible?

Tags: java, port, jakarta-mail, ssl, truststore

I'm trying to send mail using JavaMail on port 25 (no SSL) using TLS but with my own truststore (because the original cacerts truststore does not contain the needed certificates and I don't want to modify the default trust store of Java). 
I have code that is able to send a mail using TLS using the system truststore, by setting up the

```
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

property, also, setting up

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ...)
```

to point to the correct truststore when the connection goes secure works. Since its the normal port 25, I don't need to setup any *socketFactory* properties (and implementations) either. I can send mails using TLS on port 25 using the system truststore.

However.. switching system properties to be able to set up the correct trust store is kinda silly, especially on a server, when I don't know what other code wants to send mail and maybe needs to use the system properties as well, in general: I am searching for another solution neither to modify the system truststore (the *cacerts* file, making a copy of it and modify the copy is okay though!) nor the system properties currently needed to set it up.

What I tried already:

- Setting up my own SSL *socketFactory* and using my own key manager to load another truststore. This would work absolutely perfect when there wasn't a need to send on port 25 but instead I could already start a secure connection on port 465. However.. I can't do that, doing that ends up with a socket exception because I'm trying to securely connect to the mail server which isn't protected though.
- Trying to set up my own *socketFactory*, but using a normal socket for the actual communication. That basically is the same as not using my own socketFactory at all and ends up with Java using the system cacerts trustStore file.
- modifying the *cacerts* system truststore file. This works, but I don't want to modify the trust store of the system, I might not have write permissions or the keystore password could be modified, etc.
- modifying the `"javax.net.ssl.trustStore"` system property to point to my own truststore file. Works nicely, but I don't want to modify System properties either, because my code runs on a server and I don't know what other code runs there and needs the properties intact. Even saving the former state and restoring doesn't really guard against other threads using this property at the time its modified, so I don't really like this solution.

So.. in short: does anyone know a solution how I can use a non safe connection to a mail server on port 25, switch on TLS (by setting up the mail property), this internally secures the connection and using my own truststore file without modiying cacerts or a system property? Maybe there is a similar way to the socketFactory properties which is only used when the non-safe connection goes secure?

Comment: I have the same problem as you and I'm interesting in the answer you found for your problem. Can you share it? Thanks,
Valentin

Comment: Have a look at the package summary of com.sun.mail to see all properties. Basically you can set "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class" AND "mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory.class" to have a factory for SSL and Non-SSL communication. TLS can be SSL from the beginning, in my case, the beginning was Non-SSL, but switched to SSL once communication had been set up. To be able to do this per thread and not just system-wide, you just need your own Properties instance that you pass to Session.getInstance(Properties) with the according properties set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops.. found it.. there's two socketFactory properties that can be passed.. one for SSL, the other one for non-ssl factories..

Answer (score 0):

Start your application with -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=...

Then it will only be relevant to your java application and no other system properties.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly the opposite: once you start an application with a system property passed to the command line using -D... you ARE defining a system property (hence the name) that is relevant to the whole process.

Comment: The problem is, that our process hosts an amount of threads, so basically, what I needed was a way to control this by thread, or better, by connection. I found that just a little later so to me this is answered anyways, but thanks :-)